# how should i implement macro in this 8086 assembly language program for counting no. of 0's and 1's in 16 bit number?

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, tasm, emu8086

this is the source code which i am using
SOURCE: https://ankurm.com/8086-assembly-program-to-count-number-of-0s-and-1s-from-a-number/

```
DATA SEGMENT
NO DW 5648H
Z DW ?
O DW ?
DATA ENDS
 
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START:
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AX, NO
MOV BX, 00H
MOV CX, 10H
MOV DX, 00H
 
UP:
ROL AX,1
JC ONE
INC BX
JMP NXT
 
ONE:
INC DX
 
NXT:
DEC CX
JNZ UP
 
MOV Z, BX
MOV O, DX
 
INT 3
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: Note that on a CPU which isn't antique, you can replace the whole thing with an invocation of [`POPCNT`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popcnt).

Comment: You already have working code, it looks like.  A bit inefficient (e.g. could use `adc dx, 0` instead of branching, and IDK why it has two separate counters instead of getting the zero count as 16-ones after the loop).  You can put anything you like in a macro, with comments about where it wants input and which registers it steps on.  So what's the problem here?  Just macro syntax?  Which assembler are you actually using, TASM or EMU8086?

Comment: I don't get the question. The code could be optimized by unrollling e.g. by `top: shr ax,1; adc bx,0; shr ax,1; adc bx,0; shr ax,1; jz out; adc bx,0; jmp top; out:`  -- no need for a  counter, as `ax` will be zero eventually. `add ax,ax` and `shr ax,1` are probably equally good -- except that shr favours small numbers.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i am using tasm. i am very beginner in assembly programming can you please specify where exactly should i put the macro and call it again

Comment: Here's a question with a Tasm Macro that should easily convert to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575023/weird-macros-tasm